# How to close an email

Tags: saludos, cortesía, email

What is a good way to close an email in Spanish? I need something equal to closing with Best, in English to write back to a Spanish speaking colleague.

Comment: If he is a friend, I normally write "saludos", although other forms as "un saludo". If you are trying to be more polite , I would say "Un cordial saludo" or "Reciba un cordial saludo"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to *Best Regards* or *Best* would be **Atentamente**

See this quick example:

> Hola Alfredo,
>
> He recibido tu correo. Gracias por tu respuesta.
>
> Atentamente,
>
> Angel Alvarado

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be good to complete this for other possible readers.

Very formal, usually only used in cases where the email/letter will (or can) be used legally or to customers, providers, etc:

> ...
>
> Sin otro particular, atentamente,
>
> Name/company

Same case when you expect a response:

> ...
>
> Sin otro particular y a la espera de sus noticias, atentamente,
>    ...

In that case you can also use "*a la espera de sus **prontas** noticias*" if you want to "suggest" urgency without being impolite.

The form "*Sin otro particular*" is just a formality to indicate you have finished writing, and "*atentamente*" is the closing. In other Spanish speaking countries (I'm from Spain), you could find other forms for both of them, but the basics in a formal email/letter are in this order: end of the email, closing, name.

The forms proposed by *Zero Point* in the comments, "*Un cordial saludo*" and "*Reciba un cordial saludo*", are equally valid as greetings but just **a bit** less formal. A good example could be a letter to a customer where you want to seem a bit closer but still being formal.

> ...
>
> Reciba un cordial saludo,
>
> Name/company

If you think you can be less formal, you can just omit the *end of the email* part, that is the "*Sin otro particular*" form.
Note that to use both "*Sin otro particular*" and "*(reciba) un cordial saludo*" can sound a bit bizarre to a Spanish speaker. It's just too long. So, even when you can use it, commonly that form is only used in less formal writings and, again, omitting the "*Sin otro particular*".

In even less formal cases like letters to colleagues, internet forums, etc., you can use "*Saludos*", which is almost the direct translation of *Greetings*, by the way.

> ...
>
> Saludos,
>
> Name/company

You can even omit your name in that case if you are sure the reader knows who you are.
Also note that at this point, the *end of the letter* has just disappeared, and it's not returning. The only really necessary part  is the *greetings* part.

And finally, to family, friends, partners (sorry, I'm not sure if this word is right in English, I'm referring to girlfriends/boyfriends), people really close to you, just use "*Un abrazo*" (hug) or "*Besos*" (kisses), with all the affectionate, overly sweet or romantic words you'll want to add depending on the relationship.

> ...
>
> Abrazos y besos a ti y a los tuyos,
>
> Nox

Answer (score 2):

Personally, in Peru, when we talk between work colleagues who are from very different areas (and thus don't know each other), I've seen a lot of people say:

> Saludos cordiales,
>
> Fname Lname... Rest of the signature

One thing I've seen from an area that deals with particularly high profile clients is

> Cordialmente,
>
> Fname Lname

Between people on the same team, a simple "¡Gracias!" is enough. For simple emails, many times we don't even put a closer. I think this question depends a lot more on the countries (and cultures) rather than being a language-specific topic.

Comment: Welcome, DannyTalent.  Since you mentioned that the choice of closing depends on the region and culture, would you like to mention where you work?

Comment: Edited original answer!

Answer (score 0):

"Hasta la vista". Worked well in the Terminator movies!
Or ""Hasta la vista, baby" if you want to sound a little more menacing.

Comment: While this is a valid option, it could be a very poor choice in some contexts. Also, "hasta la vista" has some connotations worth considering (as opposed to some other similar choices like "nos vemos", "nos vemos pronto", etc.). A good answer could/should explain what are those connotations and in which settings (if any) it could be best or appropriate to use these choices.

Comment: Joke answers work better as comments.  Fortunately you have enough rep to write a comment!